# Tailwind CSS fontSize extend is not working for added custom class like "text-lg-bold"

Tags: tailwind-css

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    ...
    theme: {
        extend: { 
            fontSize: {
                'lg': ['20px', {
                    lineHeight: '30px',
                    fontWeight: '400'
                }],
                'lg-bold': ['20px', {
                    lineHeight: '30px',
                    fontWeight: '600'
                }],
                "4.5xl": "2.625rem"
            },
            colors: {
                "black": "#010910",
                "black-2": "rgba(1, 9, 16, 0.02)",
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms')],
    variants: {
        extend: {
            display: ["group-hover"],
        },
    },
}
```

I am using Tailwind CSS extend in tailwindconfig.js.
Extended classes are working well except text-lg-bold.

```
<span class="text-lg text-black-2">XXX</span> (Working well)
<span class="text-lg-bold text-black-2">XXX</span> (Not working)
```

I guess that this is due to ambiguity of fontSize and colors in tailwind, but I can't find out the solution.
If you have solved out the similar problem, please let me know how you have solved out.
The tailwindcss version is 3.1.8.
Thanks.

Comment: both are working just fine! I'm not sure what went wrong but have a look here : https://play.tailwindcss.com/Jpre8qohRp

Comment: Thanks @Dhaifallah, now it is working fine. I used tailwind in asp.net project and I think hot reload was not working well, so the changed configs were not applied to the view. Now all are okay and works well.